# How to access database table with drupal 7

Tags: forms, database

I am quite new to Drupal. I am creating custom module which connects to the database table. I have gone through the API documentation and created a test function and tried db connect, but there seems to be an error. This is my code:

```
function first_db_insert() {
  db_insert('imports')
    ->fields(array(
      'name' => 'Groucho',
      'address' => '123 Casablanca Ave.',
      'phone' => '555-1212',
    )
    )
  ->execute();
  drupal_set_message('database updated');
}
```

Comment: Can you describe any errors that Drupal gives you?

Comment: actually it did't give any error but data also not inserted to the database that's the problem thanks..

Comment: is there any other `not null` column in that table ? Are you inserting all required values ?

Comment: there are no  not null columns i the table,yap i insert all required values except for id which is a auto increment one

Answer (score 1):

If you have an autoincrement value for the primary key on the table you are inserting, then the `execute()` function will return you this increment value. So just check what it is returning.
But do make sure the value is defined as an autoincrement (defined as serial in hook_schema) because otherwise the returned value should not be used as it is *undefined*.

```
$nid = db_insert('node')
  ->fields(array(
    'title' => 'This is only a test.',
    'uid' => 1,
    'created' => time(),
  ))
  ->execute();
// This will ouput the $nid value to Drupal log.
 watchdog('yourmodule', "The value for nid is $nid .");
```